# Optimizing MySQL query with: join, where, group by, having

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, left-join

I have a pretty complex mysql query and I'm trying to understand if there's a way to make it use indexes. The query looks like:

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.c, COUNT(t1.li), SUM(t1.tc)
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 
ON (t1.d=t2.d AND t1.e=t2.e) 
WHERE t1.pt="XXX" GROUP BY t1.a, t1.b, t2.c
HAVING t1.li > 0 AND t1.tc > 4;
```

I am only able to get it optimized using an index on t1.pt (or the "WHERE" clause) but can't get the GROUP BY part go faster.

Is there a way to make GROUP BY use indexes when grouping is on columns from two tables?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should add indexes to joined field of both tables:

```
t1.d, t2.d, t1.e, t2.e
```

then add indexes to group by fields

```
t1.a, t1.b, t2.c
```

Also in the HAVING part I think you should write:

```
HAVING count(t1.li) > 0 AND sum(t1.tc) > 4;
```

Comment: Thanks. You are correct about the HAVING part. I did as you suggested, but EXPLAIN still gives me: "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" so I'm guessing the GROUP BY part still doesn't use any index. Is it possible to get it to use one?